¿Sobre la asignación de memoria, cómo puedo calcular qué procesos estarán en la memoria usando First Fi?
¿Alguien que pueda ayudarme a resolver este problema, de favor? Tengo mis dudas con respecto al Tiempo de Vuelta. ¿Es lo que dura el proceso hasta que termina? Es para comprender lo de First Fit, Best Fit y Worst Fit. Gracias.


Lo que no entiendo es si pueden haber más de un proceso a la vez (hace semanas hice ejercicios sobre procesos y ráfagas, y en tales casos sólo uno podía estar en memoria).
Creo que el P1 llega primero y dura hasta el tiempo 5. Sigue el P2. ¿Es ésa la respuesta?

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.
